# Slow Access query when joining SQL table with Access table

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I am using a SQL database and MS Access 2019 as the front end. The SQL database tables are linked to the Access db using an ODBC connection.

All my queries (they have multiple joined linked tables) run just fine, but as soon as I add a join to a table stored in the Access app (for example, a small table just for mapping values) the query will slow to a crawl. Doesn't matter if the joined fields are indexed or what type of join I'm using.

If anyone has seen this behaviour and found a solution I would much appreciate hearing it.

Comment: What is an *SQL database*? That's like saying *English book*. Please tag the specific RDBMS backend. Maybe you meant SQL Server? Since Access run SQL, it would it be an SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Joining tables from two separate databases requires the client app to retrieve both tables in their entirety in order to determine the rows needed. That's why it's slow.

If your Access table is small, try using a stored procedure on the SQL side with the data from Access moved to a temporary table. (Or better yet, move the Access table to SQL).